# iOS Notification Images React-Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, notifications, react-native-firebase

I have a problem to display image in my ios notification. It works on android but not in ios.

I have followed the react-native-firebase documentation and it doesn't work ....

The documentation : https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/ios-notification-images

My code to receive the notification :

```
  buildIOSNotification = (id, title, message, data = {}, options. 
  = {}) => { return {
  alertAction: options.alertAction || 'view',
  category: options.category || '',
  userInfo: {
    id: id,
    item: data,
  },
}}
```

And this is the json object that i receive :

{"action": undefined, "badge": undefined, "data": {"fcm_options": {"image": "http://192.168.1.37:4000/notification/46f72f09cfc29c6a8878dd23c4cee7d2"}, "gcm.message_id": "1622999135203061", "google.c.a.e": "1", "google.c.sender.id": "556656275748", "notificationId": "A5490592-7AA1-4B6F-82BF-3BA9D6589B0A", "remote": true}, "finish": [Function finish], "foreground": true, "id": undefined, "message": "dsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsddsdsdsdsddsdsddsdsdsdsdsdsdsds", "reply_text": undefined, "soundName": "sound_one.mp3", "title": "ddssddsdsdsdssdsddsddsdssdsdsdssdsdsdsdsdsdsd", "userInteraction": true}

Comment: What is the format of the image? Ex.: It is Base64 encoded?

Comment: I succeeded display the image of the notification payload but the problem now is that the image is only display when the app is in background and not in foreground ....